Getting sqlalchemy.exc.MissingGreenlet when relationship is defined as lazy="selectin"
So I have this class AttributeSet where I have the following relationship defined:
attribute_set_to_attribute_type: Mapped[
        List["AttributeSetToAttributeType"]
    ] = relationship(
        lazy="selectin",
        back_populates="attribute_set",
        cascade="delete, delete-orphan",
    )

I load an AttributeSet from the db:
attribute_set = await.get_attribute_set(
        attribute_set_id=attribute_set_id, session=session
    )

where
async def get_attribute_set(
    attribute_set_id: uuid.UUID, session: AsyncSession
) -> AttributeSet:
    return (
        await session.scalars(
            select(AttributeSet).where(AttributeSet.id == attribute_set_id)
        )
    ).first()

and when I try to access the items of the attribute_set_to_attribute_type collection:
for attr in attribute_set.attribute_set_to_attribute_type:
        print(attr.id)

I get a "sqlalchemy.exc.MissingGreenlet: greenlet_spawn has not been called; can't call await_only() here. Was IO attempted in an unexpected place?" error. I thought since the relationship is defined as lazy="selectin", it should load together with the AttributeSet. Can anyone explain this?

Is the session committed or closed before you access the attributes?  A proper [mre] would be useful here, so we can exactly what is happening

Have you tried awaiting it? for attr in await attribute_set.attribute_set_to_attribute_type:

Awaiting doesn't work, I get the error object InstrumentedList can't be used in 'await' expression

Found the solution. The problem wasn't in print(id) as I thought, it was later when I accessed attribute_set_to_attribute_type.attribute_set. Even though that relationship was defined with selectin:
class AttributeSetToAttributeType:
   attribute_set: Mapped[AttributeSet] = relationship(
        lazy="selectin",
        foreign_keys=[attribute_set_id],
    )

there was an error when I tried to access attribute_set_to_attribute_type.attribute_set. I solved it by doing
 for attr in attribute_set.attribute_set_to_attribute_type:
    await session.refresh(attr, ["attribute_set"])
    #do other stuff

